# Join the last inserted data/value from a table Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to show data from the last inserted record in 
the `transaction` table and I can. But I want to join the table `transaction` with the table `product` and `user`.

How to join table `transaction` with table `product` and `user`? Thank you!

This is a model transaction.php

```
function insert_data($data){
    $this->db->insert('transaction',$data);

    $id_transaction = $this->db->insert_id();
    $query = $this->db->get_where('transaction', array(
        'id_transaction' => $id_transaction
    ));

    return $query->row();
}
```

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Like what does the `product` and `user` tables look like. What you're asking to do is a `JOIN`. Take a look at the [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) documentation - specifically `$this->db->join()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assumed your table structure is simply like this :

```
Table User
|  id  |  name  |

Table Transaction 
|  id  | transaction_name  | product_id | user_id |

Table Product 
|  id  | product_name  |
```

and your purpose is want to show data using join.

basically your query should be like this :

```
SELECT user.name, product.name, transaction.transaction_name 
WHERE transaction.id = $id_transaction
JOIN product ON product.id = transaction.product_id
JOIN user ON user.id = transaction.user_id
```

i can't give the clear answer cause you're not give our more information for your purpose (you want to show data or insert) and more information about your table structure (just give the `important` structure).

i don't know about query builder in CI3, but i believe you can use my query above.

Comment: how to use in my funtion  ??

Comment: what function ?

Comment: tried something like this : `$this->db->query("My Query Above");` and then `$this->db->get();`